# Excel formula to get value based on time duration

Tags: excel

I have Excel data as per the below screenshots. I am trying to find whether it is "Out Hours" or " Business Hours" based on the start time and close time.

If time is between the start and close time, it should return "Business Hours" else " Out Of Hours".

=IF(B4=MEDIAN(B2,C2,B4),"Business Hours","Out Of Hours")

[image]

Comment: What is the problem with the formula you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a massive article about dealing with time -
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/06/24/calculate-time-excel/.
You will find everything you need.

I have found this working for you:

```
=IF(AND(HOUR(B4)+MINUTE(B4)/60>=8;HOUR(B4)+MINUTE(B4)/60<=17);"IN";"OUT")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you involve the median into this formula, you can simply do this:

```
=IF(AND(B4>=B$2;B4<=C$2);"BUSINESS HOURS";"OUTSIDE HOURS")
```

Simply said: if B4 lies between B$2 and C$2, then it's "BUSINESS HOURS", else it's outside. I'm using dollarsigns for absolute cell referencing (if you drag your formula to the next row, the value $2 doesn't change).